How to sort in Librecalc
Anyone know why Librecalc's sort dialog would suddenly be grayed out and disabled?
I added a new text column to a spreadsheet, when to alt->d->Sort based on it but the sort dialog is now completely broken. Selecting my new column literally has no effect. Then I tried selecting the column in the spreadsheet and selecting Data->Sort Descending, which worked, but now if I go back to Data->Sort, the entire sort menu is grayed out, so I can't sort by multiple columns at all.


You have not told us which version of Ubuntu you are using, as well as the version of LibreOffice. Is the data on the sheet password protected?
